# Create variable name from while loop value SQL

Tags: sql-server

First time poster on this site and I need some advice:

Is it possible to declare/create a new variable base on a while loop?

**Context:**

Financial calendar for this company assigns each date within the financial year a period (month) and a week number.  These can change each year depending on the date of the new financial year.

I want to create a function that runs a while loop to get the week and period number for a specified date.

I want to be able to say something along the lines of

```
while i > @EndDate
    if date is between such and such then week = @W(i)
end
```

I am not sure how to explain it.

I currently have my function listing ALL the week and period numbers but it looks messy and is probably not very efficient.

Can anyone advise?

Thank you

EDIT:

Apologies

My code is in SQL Server.

What I have so far is messy and a complete draft but I'll pop it in here for now.

```
declare @StartDate datetime
,   @EndDate datetime
,   @ThisDate datetime
,   @P1 datetime
,   @P2 datetime
,   @P3 datetime
,   @P4 datetime
--and so forth until P12
, @W1   datetime
, @W2   datetime
, @W3   datetime
, @W4   datetime
, @W5   datetime
--and so forth until W52

set @StartDate = '2012-12-30'

set @P1 = @StartDate + 35
set @P2 = @P1 + 28
set @P3 = @P2 + 28
set @P4 = @P3 + 35
set @P5 = @P4 + 28
set @P6 = @P5 + 28
set @P7 = @P6 + 35
set @P8 = @P7 + 28
set @P9 = @P8 + 28
set @P10 = @P9 + 35
set @P11 = @P10 + 28
set @P12 = @P11 + 28

set @W1 = @StartDate
set @W2 = @W1 + 7
set @W3 = @W2 + 7
set @W4 = @W3 + 7
set @W5 = @W4 + 7
set @W6 = @W5 + 7

--while @ThisDate > @EndDate

set i = 1

--BEGIN

    if @ThisDate between @StartDate and (@W2 - 1) 
    then @ThisWeek = W1, @ThisPeriod = P1

--END
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, please tell us which SQL database are you using, including version, looking at your code I think is SQL Server

Comment: Also, please show your entire work so far - we may be able to point you in a better direction overall.

Comment: Your question is not clear though I have slight idea of what you are trying to do. Please shed more light

Comment: Edited OP as the comment box wouldn't take all my code.

Comment: Also - although the financial year changes start dates they always follow the 544544544544 pattern for the weeks per period

Comment: Just as a side note, there is what looks to me like an inconsistency in how you identify periods and weeks. In particular, the weeks are identified by their beginning dates (the first week is assigned just `@StartDate`) while the periods appear to be identified by their ending dates or maybe even the following periods' beginning dates (the first period is assigned `@StartDate + 35` rather than `@StartDate`). Maybe there's a reason for that, I can't possibly know, of course. Just thought I'd tell you in case that *was* an issue.

Comment: Thanks @AndriyM, I didn't notice that! It is an inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to have an auxiliary table listing the weeks and associated periods, and then join on that table for tables containing dates to be checked.

Ex:

```
SELECT 
    periods.week, tbl.rdate
FROM
    tbl, periods
WHERE 
    tbl.rdate BETWEEN periods.startdate AND periods.enddate
```

would give you the week `periods.week` associated to the date `tbl.rdate`, with a table `periods` having columns `week`, `startdate`, `enddate` for the week number and its start and end dates. You could add a supplementary (indexed) column for the financial year if your database has to keep records over several years, and add a constraint on this column in your queries to reduce the scan to a single financial year. One such year being 52 rows in average, it should not be too problematic to keep 20 years worth of periods, or even tune the db to keep the table in memory.